# owner is required in Django template

Tags: python, django

I have two identical views in which I am editing an existing model record

Views.py

```
def edit_product(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    form = Producteditform(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('employee:products_table')
    return render(request, 'packsapp/employee/employeeProductEditForm.html', {'form': form})

def edit_warehouse(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Warehouse, pk=pk)
    form = Warehouseeditform(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('employee:warehouse_table')
    return render(request, 'packsapp/employee/warehouseEditForm.html', {'form': form})
```

Forms.py

```
class Producteditform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'


class Warehouseeditform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Warehouse
        fields = '__all__'
```

Models.py

```
class Warehouse(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employee_warehouse_owner')
    warehouse_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    warehouse_email = models.EmailField(max_length=500, default=0)
    warehouse_contact = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    product_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    product_hsn_code = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    product_owner = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_owner')
```

When I edit a product it saves the form without any error but when i try to do the same with warehouse it refreshed without any error and was not proceeding.
Then with `{{ form.errors }}` it says :  owner This field is required.

Why does it need owner in the warehouse edit form but not in the product edit form ?

Comment: May be if form.is_valid(): is failing for warehouse can you put log and check

Comment: As your  model class have Owner field in WareHouse but not in Product its throwing error.  You are sending employee data through form ??

Comment: Does your product has a owner associated with already, so that when you edit the Product you don't modify the owner field but save works. And same way does the warehouse also has a owner assosicated with it ?

Comment: Unrelated, but your views are not correctly coded. You should test on `request.method` before even trying to validate the form.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting `blank=True` and `null=True` to make the `ForeignKey` attribute optional.

By default a `ForeignKey` attribute is always `required` to be present on the form submission.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted the answer without reading my above comment for it.

Comment: Both Products and Warehouse are connected to employee via foreignkey so it's strange that products is not throwing this error but warehouse is

Comment: also I cannot add null = True in a foreignkey field, I need it

Comment: You mean you need it to be a required field ? Then how do you expect it to not raise error when this field is left empty? Also does your product object has owner associated with it before you edit it ? If it has then it won't throw the error.

Comment: Isn't foreignkey field is automatically a required field and I get that It should throw the error, what I don't understand is why Products edit form is not throwing the same error

Comment: Does your product object has `product_owner` value already set before you edit it ?

Comment: Yes it does have a `product_owner` before editing also my warehouse has `owner` at the time of editing